# How to stop a foreach loop data from repeating onto the next iteration?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a foreach that loops multiple times, `$x as $amount` in this case. Inside the loop, I have another foreach that uses preg_match_all to match some data from the `$text as $catch` and throws them into an array to be used elsewhere, in this case we're setting it as `$instructions`.

We're now sending the both of the data's from each loop into a function, `passData($instructions, $amount)`.

**The issue:**
As we're calling the `passData()` function from inside the `$x` loop, the data being matched the `$instructions` array keeps repeating with each iteration as shown below, but the result I'm looking for to not pass the same data onto the next array, following this example each array should contain the same number of keys 0 - 4, not 0 - 9.

```
Array is:1
Array
(
    [0] => first paragraph goes here
    [1] => http://www.google.com/g_logo.jpg
    [2] => second paragraph is also here
    [3] => third paragraph is much longer then the rest
    [4] => http://www.facebook.com/f_logo.jpg
)
Array is:2
Array
(
    [0] => first paragraph goes here
    [1] => http://www.google.com/g_logo.jpg
    [2] => second paragraph is also here
    [3] => third paragraph is much longer then the rest
    [4] => http://www.facebook.com/f_logo.jpg
    [5] => first paragraph goes here
    [6] => http://www.google.com/g_logo.jpg
    [7] => second paragraph is also here
    [8] => third paragraph is much longer then the rest
    [9] => http://www.facebook.com/f_logo.jpg
)
```

**What I've tried:**
The only solution I could come up with was calling [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) on the `$text` after it's foreach loop, but it did not resolve the issue.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
function passData($a, $b){
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Array is:' . $b, '</br>';
    print_r($a);
    echo '</pre>';
}

function tryFunc(){

    $x = ['1','2'];
    foreach($x as $amount){

        $text = [
            '1. first paragraph goes here',
            '<img src="http://www.google.com/g_logo.jpg">',
            '2. second paragraph is also here',
            '3. third paragraph is much longer then the rest',
            '<img src="http://www.facebook.com/f_logo.jpg">'
        ];

        foreach($text as $catch){
            if(preg_match_all("/(?:\d)\. (.*)/", $catch, $output_array)) {
                foreach($output_array[1] as $instructions_output){
                    $instructions[] = $instructions_output;
                }
            }
            if(preg_match_all("/<*img[^>]*src *= *[\"\']?([^\"\']*)/", $catch, $cought_array)) {
                $instructions[] = $cought_array[1][0];
            }
        }

        if(passData($instructions, $amount)){
            echo 'passed';
        }
    }
}

tryFunc();
```

Comment: Try using break

Comment: No luck, if it still accepted numerical arguments I'd be able to pass in the last iteration key, nonetheless I tried with, to no avail.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make `$instructions` start off as a new empty array for each item in the `$x` array. If so, you could put `$instructions = array();` inside the first `foreach`, for example immediately before the `$text = ...` line  (i.e. on line 12 of your code sample above).

Comment: @salathe Yes, that's exactly it and it worked. Now, that's something new I learned, I didn't realize I needed to set the $instructions as an empty array before calling it, I thought using it directly with the [] it'd be the same as defining it before it's called. Thank you.